# How to make c# form mirrored?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have some text in a web browser  on my form in visual studio, this form is going to be displayed on a big screen and it's content need to be mirrored(flipped) in order to be seen on the other place through mirror. It is not rotation actually. I know it is possible to do it with images, but it is not applicable in my case, because browser's document is scrolling.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this usually done by the projector settings? Its a pretty common need i different big screen settings.

Maybe the graphics card software has some property for this?

Comment: I read nvidia graphics card's tutorial and did not find anything concerning this :(

Comment: Then try the projector. Any projector of deasent standard will be able to flip the image, they are ment to be able to back-project, be upside down and so forth. It should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the graphic card support this feature.
You don't need to code it.